# How to distinguish between multiple textField returns?

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm a bit inexperienced in regards to UIKit..

So I have multiple `UITextField` :

```
let companyTF = JobTextField(placeholder: "Company")
let positionTF = JobTextField(placeholder: "Position")
let hiringManagerTF = JobTextField(placeholder: "Hiring Manager")
let typeTF = JobTextField(placeholder: "Type")
```

Of course I had to make the parent VC conform to the delegate

```
extension JobAddVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("Hello")
        return true
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that same code will run for every text field of this delegate class..

What is the solution here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to compare `textfield` in delegate method

eg.

suppose your first textfield name is `compantTextfield`(Outlet bind name)

```
if textfield == compantTextfield {
print("Hello")
}
```